# Multi index Pandas dataframe and export in excel

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have this multi-index dataframe:

```
                Value
                Year    2010    2011    2012    2013    2014    2015    2016    2017    2018
Partner Product Reporter                                    
FRA         111   ARG   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.0
                  ARM   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.0
                  AUT   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.0
                  BEL   0.01    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.01    0.01    0.01    0.0
                  BGR   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.0
                  CAN   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.0
            112   ARG   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.0
                  ARM   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.0
                  AUT   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.0
                  BEL   0.01    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.01    0.01    0.01    0.0
                  BGR   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.0
                  CAN   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.0   
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
            9900  OMN   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.0
                  PAK   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.0
                  PAN   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.0
                  PER   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.0
                  PHL   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.0
```

It includes 1 element in column "Partner" and 444 element in column "Product" (all those elements are included in a list called "Products").
I need to create 444 dataframes (maybe with a for cicle) for any product and save them in an excel file (better if anyone in different sheets).
May you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Idea is use [`ExcelWriter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html) and create new sheets in loop by `groupby`:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx') as writer:  
    for i, g in df.sort_index(level=1, ascending=False).groupby(level=1, sort=False):
        g.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=f'Sheet_name_{i}')
```

Comment: It work perfectly! Do you know how to save them in descending order for every product?

Comment: @olcesi - Answer was edited by [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and added `sort=False` to `groupby`